# Updating value in Redis with C#

Tags: c#, redis

I running the Windows server version of Redis and then have a little client application, and I cant find out how I update a value in a datatype I already have in the database

I have this Leader class I would like to update if it exists for a given District, else create an new entry

```
public class Leader
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public District District { get; set; }
}

    public void SetLeader(District district, Employee employee)
    {
        using (var leaderSession = _redisClient.GetTypedClient<Leader>())
        {
            var leader = leaderSession.GetAll().SingleOrDefault(x => x.District.Id == district.Id);
            if (leader != null)
            {
                leader.Employee = employee;
            }
            else
            {
                leader = new Leader{District = district, Employee = employee};
            }
            leaderSession.Store(leader);
        }
    }
```

But when I do this I just get an extra entry in the database, so Store is not the right command to use, but which should I use?

The only solution I can come up with is delete the old one and store a new one, but thats seems a bit ineffective? (Not that it matters in my example, but still)

**Edit**: doing delete dont work either, it still creates a new one and keeps the old one.

```
    public void SetLeader(District district, Employee employee)
    {
        using (var leaderSession = _redisClient.GetTypedClient<Leader>())
        {
            var leader = leaderSession.GetAll().SingleOrDefault(x => x.District.Id == district.Id);
            if (leader != null)
            {
                leaderSession.Delete(leader);
            }

            leader = new Leader { District = district, Employee = employee };
            leaderSession.Store(leader);
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2** Adding a Id field to Leader was apparently necessary for it to distinguish the different rows

So changing it to this works

```
public class Leader
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public District District { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a Id field to Leader was apparently necessary for it to distinguish the different rows

So changing it to this works

```
public class Leader
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public District District { get; set; }
}
```